# Super key not working

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've got a desktop running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with a Steelseries Apex 350 keyboard. How can I make the super key work? Nothing happens when I press it, although it is being detected

[image]

Comment: Work for what? Do you have KDE?

Comment: I want it to open dash. No, GNOME

Comment: Hmm. It should open it. Does this keyboard have two super keys maybe?

Comment: Two actually.  https://media.steelseriescdn.com/filer_public/94/71/94711d5e-4949-474f-a650-35d68e32a722/apex500_leadin_proof2_r.png

Comment: Just to make sure, you are pressing the Winkey and not the Steelseries one right?

Comment: the program `xev` will provide the keycode of the key you are pushing. This will be helpful to know if you wish to remap it or use it to activate a specific function. Please [edit] the output of `xev` when you push the button into your question.

Comment: I am pressing the winkey. (None of them are working) But my computer does acknowledge them. I would prefer if both worked, but I would be be happy just being able to use one of them.  http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1575724/8c021a51d37572cef2596c3dbe2926d7

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the `super` was disabled by default. A solution can be found here: http://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/how12108/anleitung-zum-aktivieren-der-ubuntu-super-taste-auf-dell-oem-ubuntu-installationen?lang=de

If it is disabled, find official release notes how to revert this change.

In case this is not intentionally disabled feature then just install:
`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
and look up the `Ubuntu Unity plugin` usage.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Apex Pro. For me, it turned out that keyboard switches some kind of mode when I press the SteelSeries function key and then the left Windows key. Doing so toggles the Windows key's color between red and blue, and if I leave it on blue, it no longer registers as `Super`. I have no idea what the purpose of the other "mode" is and the [manual](https://downloads.steelseriescdn.com/guides/Apex_Pro_PIG_03_web_MP.pdf) doesn't mention it.