# Super key does not open dash on 16.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-dash

Basically I have a duplicate issue of this guy: [Super key not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823461/super-key-not-working)

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> opens the "Run a command" shortcut, <kbd>ALT</kbd> by itself opens the HUD, but I cannot use any shortcut to open the Dash, which is making Unity very frustrating to use. I can't seem to find a keyboard shortcut setting for it. I can bind other actions to Super and they work as expected, but I don't see any setting to let me use Super to open the Dash...

Comment: Try installing `compizconfig-settings-manager` and under Unity Plugin,  "Launcher" tab , check if your Super key is unset. See the screenshot of how it's supposed to look: http://imgur.com/a/aY8PX If it's disabled , there's the problem

Answer (score 34):

I had the same issue on 16.04.

I used this command to enable Super key for opening the Unity launcher and it worked for me

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher "'Enabled'"
```

Comment: Yes it worked, the key value was set to 'Disabled' by default

Comment: it worked after I logged out.

Comment: This should definitely be marked as the answer, worked a charm immediately!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and this worked for me in 16.04

Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and `dconf-editor`.

Open `dconf-editor`: navigate to `org > compiz > unity > profiles > plugins > unityshell` and change the value of key `show-launcher` to `<Super>`.

Comment: Would try this but I have since moved to Gnome 3 where the super key works fine. But this sounds like bingo. Wish I could test it out.

Comment: Minor point:  for me, it was `org` -> `compiz` -> `profiles` -> `unity` -> `plugins` -> `unityshell`.

Comment: Didn't work for me because compiz refused to accept the `<super>` key. Posted a question on the subject: [Values cannot be changed in CompizConfig System Manager (CCSM) when using <super>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008036/values-cannot-be-changed-in-compizconfig-system-manager-ccsm-when-using-super)

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this happen , I'm not quite sure why but unity sometimes crashes and becomes unclickable.

I workaround it by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and typing

```
unity --replace
```

The screen will flash as unity reloads and it should be back to normal.

If that doesn't work you can try resetting your unity config with the following commands, you might need to install unity-tweak-tool first.

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately. This has never worked, not even off of a fresh boot.

Comment: i've added some reset instructions