# Values cannot be changed in CompizConfig System Manager (CCSM) when using <super>

Tags: 16.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz

I'm trying to change the value "Left Maximize" to `<Control><Super>Left`, succeeding in grabbing the key combination.

But after a second, the value returns to the previous key combination. See screencap below.

**What's preventing me from changing the key combination and how can I bypass it?** Thanks.

**UPDATE**: It seems that only shortcuts with the `<super>` key are being reverted back to default. (Changed the question's title)

* Note that this is a pre-installed version for Dell.

[image: a].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround but **still don't understand why the super key is locked from usage.**

Steps for the workaround:

**1.** Change the key in CCSM to something without super (Should work).

**2.** Find the new key in [dconf dump](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169704/how-to-search-dconf-for-keys-or-values). `dconf dump / | less` + search for the new key combination. Found something of the following:

`[org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/grid]`

`put-maximize-key='<Control><Alt>Up'`

`put-restore-key='<Control><Alt>Down'`

**`left-maximize='<Alt>Left'`**

**3.** Write the new value. Example:

`dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/grid/left-maximize "'<Super><Control>Left'"` (see the **left-maximize** in the command)

**4.** Check that it was written correctly:

`$ dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/grid/left-maximize`

`'<Super><Control>Left'`